# Get запрос на Winsock Delphi

Tags: delphi, winsock

Как отправить GET запрос вида **site.ru/index.php?id=457&vers=27**

Есть такой код:

```
procedure HTTPGet(URL,Query:String);   //HTTPGet('site.ru','/index.php?id=123');   
 var   
   WSAData1: TWSAData;   
   SockAddr1:TSockAddr;   
   Socket1: TSocket;   
   Buffer1:string;   
   i,d:integer;

 begin   
 //Если при вызове, функция выдала значение не равное "0", то выходим из функции.   
   if WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), WSAData1)<>0 then   
     Exit;   
   Socket1:=Socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0); // Создаём Socket   
   if Socket1=INVALID_SOCKET then   
     Exit; // Если при создании возникла ошибка, то выходим из функции.   
   SockAddr1.sin_family:=AF_INET; // Указываем спецификацию типа "AF_INET" для TCP/IP   
   SockAddr1.sin_addr:=pinaddr(gethostbyname(PChar(URL))^.h_addr^)^; // Тута мы вводим ссылку, получаем IP адрес сайта.   
   SockAddr1.sin_port:=htons(80); //Ну порт с которым всегда работаем "80"   
   if Connect(Socket1,SockAddr1,SizeOf(SockAddr1))<>0 then   
     exit; //Если при подключении (не отправке), функция возвращает значение не равное "0", то выходим из функции.

   Buffer1:='GET '+query+' HTTP/1.1'#13#10+   
            'Host: '+URL+#13#10+   
            'Connection: close'#13#10+   
            #13#10;   
   // Выше мы составили Header

   send(Socket1,Buffer1[1],Length(Buffer1),0); //без возвращаемого значения   
 end;
```

Но он под простой get запрос.
Подскажите, что нужно переделать, чтобы отправить веб-серверу 2 нужных мне значения в URL?

Подозреваю что здесь:

```
Buffer1:='GET '+query+' HTTP/1.1'#13#10+   
            'Host: '+URL+#13#10+   
            'Connection: close'#13#10+   
            #13#10;
```

Но как???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно же, что в параметр `Query` при вызове функции нужно положить ваш запрос: `/index.php?id=457&vers=27`